# What is equivalent to parent() when looking for any ancestor

Tags: jquery, find, parent-child, selector, parent

When I'm looking for children of an element I use the following lines.

```
var myself = $(donkey);
var myProblems = myself.children("*");
var notMyProblems = myself.find("*");
```

However, when going in the opposite direction, I can use the line below but I haven't found the recurrent equivalent to the *find* method. Isn't there such thing?

```
var myself = $(donkey);
var problemCreator = myself.parent();
```

As an example, I'd like to find the table element that contains a row that contains a divisor that contains a span that contains a button that was clicked. I can do something like this.

```
var clickaroo = $(event.target);
var holder = clickaroo.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();
```

However, it looks ugly and is fragile, in case the button is nested in an unexpected or unforseen extra div or span. I'd like to use something like this.

```
var clickaroo = $(event.target);
var holder = clickaroo.superParent("table");
```

I've googlearched for it but got nada. Am I using wrong keywords or is there no such function?

Comment: I think you want closest: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: This is **precisely** what I was looking for. Unintuitive name, in my opinion. You'd need to post it as a reply so that I can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you're looking for is *closest()*.

If you're trying to target elements of class *findMe*, you can use the following five methods.

```
var self = $("#myMyselfAndI");
var oneLevelDown = self.children(".findMe");
var anyLevelDown = self.find(".findMe");
var oneLevelUp = self.parent();
var anyLevelUp = self.closest(".findMe");
var allUppwards = self.parents();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search upwards in the DOM there are a few options. If you use `.parent()` it will look for an immediate parent of the node but if you use `parents(selector)` the search will traverse the tree upwards, returning all matches. So instead of `find` you can do this

```
var myself = $(donkey);
var parents = myself.parents();
```

Comment: You're correct. However, going **upwards** is always producing a single parent element per level (precisely one element must be an ancestor of the current one). In most cases I've had, I only need to locate the **first** occurrence of an ancestor that satisfies a condition, so *closest()* seems even better alternative. Nevertheless, your answer is correct - take a peek at the other answer, though.

Comment: @KonradViltersten yes I omitted it because both methods you used in your post (`children` and `find`) behave in precisely that manner. Returning all matches not just one